# how do I make an integer equal true

Tags: java, type-conversion, int, boolean, bluej

I am trying to make an if statement which checks if an int = true but I keep getting an error which says that int and boolean are incomparable types. Is there a way to make it work

`if (board[i + k][j + l] == true){`

Answer (score 1):

An `int` will never equal `true`, in some languages a `1` and `true` are equal, but Java is not one of them. Assuming your code originated in such a language,

```
if (board[i + k][j + l] == 1) {
```

or

```
if (board[i + k][j + l] != 1) {
```

to cover the contrary case, or even

```
if (board[i + k][j + l] != 0) {
```

or

```
if (board[i + k][j + l] == 0) {
```

But you can't write `if ((boolean) 1)` because that is not legal syntax in Java.

Answer (score 0):

This would work if your board array is of type boolean. For Example:

```
    boolean[][] board = new boolean[3][3];
    board[0][0] = true;
    board[0][1] = false;
    board[0][2] = true;
    board[1][0] = false;
    board[1][1] = true;
    board[1][2] = false;
    board[2][0] = true;
    board[2][1] = false;
    board[2][2] = true;

    int i=0;
    int j=1;
    int k=0;
    int l=1;

    if (board[i + k][j + l] == true){
        System.out.println("true");
    } else {
        System.out.println("false");            
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I got your question and here's the answer to it:-

You cannot make an **int/Integer** datatype to give you your final result as **True/False**, it is available in few programming languages but here in **Java** you can do it with Boolean datatype as **boolean**.

Here's a **bonus point**:- You can use a **method** to make an integer give your answer as **True/False**.

> Here's the **Syntax** which might help you.

**Syntax:**

**Following is the declaration of equals() method:
public boolean equals(Object obj)**

Here is a **simple code snippet** as an example with this **method**:-

```
public class IntegerEqualsExample1 {  
public static void main(String[] args) {          
    Integer obj1 = new Integer(43);  
    Integer obj2 = new Integer(78);  
    System.out.print("obj1 and obj2 are equal. True or False? = ");  
    System.out.println(obj1.equals(obj2));                    
    obj1 = new Integer(55);  
    obj2 = new Integer(55);  
    System.out.print("obj1 and obj2 are equal. True or false? = ");  
    System.out.println(obj1.equals(obj2));                 
}
```

}

> And here is the **output** of the **code snippet**:-

```
obj1 and obj2 are equal. True or False? = false
obj1 and obj2 are equal. True or false? = true
```

You can check out this website which can help you out with your code by [clicking here](https://www.javatpoint.com/java-integer-equals-method).

I hope this has solved your problem .